# Facebook and twitter posts

Tags: facebook, posts

Thanks for earlier responses, it helped me alot.

I have one more requirement, I want to display all public posts of celebrities from Facebook and Twitter on my website. Is there anyway I can do this. Could you please guide me on how to get this thing done. Please help me.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

There are twitter apis available, Tweepy and facebook-sdk in python. I believe that these should come in handy!

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i have to do this site in PHP.

Comment: Both Facebook and Twitter have PHP SDKs/libraries available.